# Ubuntu 14.04.01: inxi -Z -i WAN None detected!

Tags: networking

I have two servers, both Ubuntu 14.04.01, kernel 3.16.0-49-generic. On both servers I have the same script to detect my WAN ip address and email it to me. In order to get my WAN IP address I'm using `inxi -Z -i` . On the first everything works fine. On the second inxi gives me "None detected!" The version of inxi is the same on both servers: 1.9.17
Currently I'm using external source to get my WAN IP address, which I do not like it.

Any suggestions, ideas? 
Thanks 
Thanassis

Comment: As of today, after reboot,  the first server gives me "WAN IP: None detected!" too!

Answer (score 0):

You probably were banned from the service is my guess due to abuse. How many times an hour were you running this command? Post the contents of that script that runs that command, that might show the source of the problem.

Where are the servers located? And why do they need their WAN checked? Most servers have static IP addresses, except for home things I guess.

Note that inxi has an option to set alternate IP WAN address source, you have to set the script configuration file with it.

However, inxi requires a specific format, where there is one single line of output from the IP source, and the ip address is the last item in that line of output, I believe it's the last.

Anyone who plans on sending a large number of requests to remote addresses without prior approval from that source in general can count on getting banned from those services, as a rule.

Comment: I do not use any service for getting my WAN IP address. I'm using this `inxi -Z -i |grep WAN | awk '{print $5}'` in my bash script. The script is running in each server. 
The static IP address of a server has to do with the LAN not the WAN. This is a home application.
Although it seems that it will not help in this situation, could you direct me to the **alternate IP WAN address source** ?

Comment: A wan address always comes from an external source, unless the server itself is not firewalled and its LAN IP is the same as its WAN IP, which is rare. So of course you are getting the WAN IP from an external source. You didn't answer the other questions however, how often are you running this command on the server? Anything, iincluding inxi, that shows you the WAN of a device on a LAN is getting that data from an external source.(http://smxi.org/docs/inxi-configuration.htm inxi docs)

Comment: And also, how many of these 'servers' are there?

Comment: Thanks for the link but I did not find any useful info in the smxi docs for my issue. 
If you read my original post and my comments, you'll see that I have answered all your 'questions': 2 (home) servers [BTW in two different locations/WANs], the command as shown in my first comment, the purpose is to get alert email when the WAN IP is changed. 
Now can you explain me how the inxi command uses an external source to give me my WAN IP address. By saying 'external source' I presume that you mean beyond my ADSL router, right? If this is the case so which is that external source by default?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation tells you how to add custom updates to the inxi defaults. The inxi defaults are found at the top of the inxi file. You seem reluctant to say how many times an hour you were running this command on, that's fine, it must have been enough to get banned, so that's whatever. I think you may be unclear on what WAN vs LAN IP addresses are. Your WAN address IS the external address of your router, just as all systems inside LANs have the WAN of their external router that faces the internet. So to get the address of that router requires you going outside your LAN, and then seeing where the request came from. There's tons of places online that give you this information, or you can just set up a simple php script on any web server that echoes out the IP, no need for inxi or anything like inxi:

```
<?php echo $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]; ?>
```

that would be the entire contents of that web page/file. You could call it, say, ip.php. Or you can use any other service, inxi  isn't needed, just wget or lynx the file. Like:

```
lynx -dump <your url ip tool>
```

OR

```
wget -O <your ip url tool>
```

etc. Lots of ways to do it. Setting up your own external web page for it is the easiest, but any online what is my ip tool works fine as long as you know its output format. Good luck.

Comment: Probably it was my mistake: In my original post I wrote  _Currently I'm using external source to get my WAN IP address_, meaning as a workaround until I can fix the issue with the **inxi** tool. That's why I think that I misled you and you took for granted that I have been banned due to frequent queries for my WAN IP and so you focused on how to use  external  source for getting WAN IP. I do not like to use external sources. 
SO what's going wrong with **inxi** and it doesn't give me the WAN IP address, anymore? The documentation doesn't focus on WAN IP, except for using **-i** parameter.

Comment: As I already said, you can't get a WAN IP without using an external source, inxi is no exception to this rule. So you were probably blocked from the external source inxi uses, as I said in my first response. The number of requests per hour probably triggered this block, how many per hour were there? inxi isn't magic, it can't' look outside of your network, or inside your router, to see the assigned WAN address without doing what everyone else does, use an external WAN IP source.